# Переворот элементов массива между максимальным и минимальным

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не получается перевернуть массив между максимальным и минимальным элементами.
Собственно, сам код:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus")
    int n = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int *mass;
    mass = new int[n];
    int x;
    int min = 999;
    int max = -999;
    int kz, nz;
    cout << "Введите кол-во элементов массива: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Введите элементы массива: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> mass[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (mass[i] > max)
        {
            max = mass[i];
        }
        if (mass[i] < min)
        {
            min = mass[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "Максимальный элемент равен: " << max << ", а минимальный: " << min;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (mass[i] = max)
        {
            do
            {
                cout << mass[i - 1];

            } while (mass[i] != min);
        }
        else{
            cout << "error";
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: 1) Не надо присваивать начальным min/max некие значения 999 и -999. Они инициализируются нулём. 2) Не надо запоминать в min/max значение элемента, там надо запоминать индекс элемента. И сравнивать, есссно, начинать не с нулевого, а с первого элемента. 3) Что такое "перевернуть массив"? 4) Не забудьте учесть, что минимальный элемент может быть как до, так и после максимального. 5) Что делать, если в массиве есть два (и более) элементов с одинаковым максимальным (и/или минимальным) значением?

Answer (score 1):

```
int n = 0;
...
mass = new int[n];
```

Ну и зачем вам массив нулевой длины?

И еще - вы *точно* хотели присваивать здесь: `if (mass[i] = max)`, а не сравнивать?...

Ну и - я бы делал примерно так:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    cout << "Введите кол-во элементов массива: ";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Введите элементы массива: ";
    for (int k, i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> k;
        v.push_back(k);
    }
    auto mM = minmax_element(v.begin(),v.end());
    if (mM.first > mM.second)
        swap(mM.first,mM.second);
    if (mM.first != mM.second)
        reverse(++mM.first,mM.second);
    for(auto i: v) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: А и действительно зачем ТС'у массив нулевой длины и присваивание в `if`?